# Space complexity of algorithm with variable declared inside loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, space-complexity

Can someone please explain what would be the **space complexity** of below code? Would it be **O(1)** or **O(N)**?

```c#
public int Run(int no)
{
    for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
    {
        int temp = i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it might be `O(N)`? Actually, it's probably `O(0)` as compilers are very likely to optimise this out...

Comment: The only way it would be O(N) would be if each iteration of the loop allocates additional memory for a new copy of `temp`. I would guess that's *not* happening, but you haven't said what language this is.

Comment: Actually, I was following a video on youtube which did give an impression that variable declared inside a loop would be O(N), which is in itself very surprising for me. :) So, thought better to get few other opinions. :) Language is C#.

Comment: Sometimes if I want to see what's happening at a lower level in a piece of C# code, I'll type up a little snippet in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and then check out the IL that my code compiles into. Doing that in this case will show you that the same storage location is used for `temp` in each iteration of the loop. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the loop makes it into the compiled code, the space used is O(1). The memory location for `temp` is the same for all iterations.

Comment: @AbhilashNK I don't know that tool but I doubt that what you saw was actually the memory address of the local variable.